# Dark mode with expanding circle animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, keyframe

I got night mode(or maybe dark mode) toggle button at the top-right corner of my page.

[This is a link for perfect example that shows what I want to do](https://codepen.io/sharafc/pen/JjXgzLv)

However, not like the link above, I toggle night mode like the code below.

**HTML**
I use data-theme attribute to change the mode. (night > light or light > night)

```
<body data-theme="">
    <div class="toggle" id="switch" onclick="toggleDarkMode()"></div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
function toggleDarkMode() {
    var dataTheme = $('body').attr('data-theme');
    
    if(dataTheme == 'dark') {   
        $('body').attr('data-theme', 'light');
    } else {
        $('body').attr('data-theme', 'dark');
    }
};
```

I need your advice how to toggle night mode with expanding circle animation with keyframe.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

A very simple but effective solution for this would be to create a `class` `dark` where you can put all your dark mode stylings. Then add or remove that `class` on a click `eventListener()`

```js
document.querySelector('.toggle').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.className = body.className !== 'dark' && 'dark';
})
```

```css
.dark {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Hello world</p>
  <button class='toggle'>Dark Mode</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to target the body on the basis of the `data-theme` attribute and style it appropriately.

```js
function toggleDarkMode() {
  var dataTheme = $('body').attr('data-theme');

  if (dataTheme == 'dark') {
    $('body').attr('data-theme', 'light');
  } else {
    $('body').attr('data-theme', 'dark');
  }
};
```

```css
body[data-theme="light"] {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

body[data-theme="dark"] {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body data-theme="light">
  <p>Hello world</p>
  <button class="toggle" id="switch" onclick="toggleDarkMode()">Toggle Theme</button>
</body>
```

This would allow you to use whatever CSS styling you like, such as from the link provided in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#switch").click(function(){
       var dataTheme = $('body').attr('data-theme');
       if(dataTheme == 'dark') {   
           $('body').attr('data-theme', 'light');
       } else {
           $('body').attr('data-theme', 'dark');
       }
     };
});
</script>
```